# jump to anchor + execute ajax + open jquery-ui accordion tab in one function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make it so when the user clicks the hyperlink below it  (1) anchors to #suggestions, (2) hits the url suggestions.php?appid=70&commentid=25961 and nothing more (arbitrary numbers used for this example -- this is not important), then (3) opens the jquery-ui accordion #suggestions.

I'm not sure why but when I click the URL the ajax function is not being executed nor is the accordion #suggestions opening. I tried adding an alert("foobar"); at the end of the function, but nothing happens and there must be a syntax error somewhere.

Edit: I checked the syntax and the warnings are:

```
Expected '"' and instead saw '''.
type: 'GET',
5.6Expected '"' and instead saw '''.
url: 'forumsetcomment.php',
9.35Unexpected trailing space.
window.location = "#suggestions"    
18.9Expected '/'.
</script>
```

html:

```
<a href="#suggestions" class="readmore">Read More</a>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".readmore").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'forumsetcomment.php',
data: {appid:70, commentid:25961},
complete: function(data){
refreshMyForum();
window.location = "#suggestions"    
$( "#suggestions" ).accordion({
heightStyle: "content",
collapsible: true,
active: false
});
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your jQuery code in a `$(document).ready(function(){/* Your jQuery Code Here*/});`

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ba6bIZ8BWu866jJ4qIuB?p=preview)

To fix the last issue with the jQuery UI Accordion not opening.

Try this:

```
$( "#suggestions" ).accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
});
```

Comment: Hmm. I used the same code as in Plunker and I don't even see the alert.

Comment: The ajax is firing when I check the network activity using Chrome Developer Tools in the plunker I linked above. 

There do not appear to be any syntax errors in the code, but it does claim that the function `refreshMyForum` is undefined. 

Are you able to visit the ajax url directly in your browser?

Comment: Hey there was a typo in refreshMyForum that fixed two of the three issues (ajax+jumping to the correct anchor tag). The last one is the jquery-ui accordion not opening.             $( "#suggestions" ).accordion({ is certainly not a misspelling.  https://jqueryui.com/accordion/ if this helps debunk things

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant HTML (#suggestions container) and JS for the accordion.